# how can i check parameter in while loop for each item in array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, while-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get titles from old website.

The problem that i'm getting in some cases - `null` value.
Therefore, I have tried to do a while loop and change the URL.

Is my `While` loop in the right place?

The procedure is like this:

1. open file
2. get url
3. check url
4. get title
5. print title
6. while title = null):
7. replace part of the url and check url again

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
import xlrd
import lxml

# set file location
os.chdir("/excel_files")

# set the name of the file
file_name = "old.xlsx"

# open workbook
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)

# set existing worksheet
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)


temp_list = [20131022212405,20090127003537,2009012702352,]

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    try:
        u = sheet.cell_value(i,1)
    html = urlopen(u)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features='lxml')
    # get title
    title = str(bsObj.title)
    print('row no. ',i, 'title is :' , title)
except:
    title = 'null'
while (title == 'null'):
    try:
        u = u.replace(temp_list[i], temp_list[i + 1])
        html = urlopen(u)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features='lxml')
        title = str(bsObj.title)
    except:
        print('title is :',title)
```

I'm getting `null` all the time - instead of getting only the row that actually is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `try/except` indentation in the first `for` loop (`for i in range(sheet.nrows):`) is wrong, `try` and `except` should be on the same level.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i can't put try/except in the same level with for  - i'm getting errors